Enclosure for thermal camera
I want to make a thermal camera system for wildlife recording over multiple nights. I have created a low resolution system with a infiray sensor, which works well at 25fps.
Some enclosures I have (ABS plastic) do not work with thermal vision (IR light does not pass through).
I want to keep the enclosure relatively low cost.
I am not looking for a perfect image but do need the system to be ip65 complaint.
Does anyone know of any suitable enclosures which infrared (thermal) can pass through? I have seen flir windows which I could fit onto a standard enclosure but these are really expensive? If anyone knows any other clever ways to achieve this let me know.
Abs enclosure
Maybe a plastic which lets infrared through will be suitable (though not as perfect as germanium)

there are commercial available wildlife cameras for <$50 with infrared capabilities, does that exceed your budget?

Make your enclosure thin. Also consider testing some common materials with your infiray sensor.
